# Is it possible for Elastic Beanstalk to use a full domain name for a health check?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

My company has a large application that hosts 3 separate domains with a centralized core. In moving from Heroku, we've gone with Elastic Beanstalk which largely has been just fine.

However, since the application has multiple domain names, the health check at the base URL of "/" fails, since the application does not listen to anything on `[subdomain].elasticbeanstalk.com`, it returns it as a fail and the environments are therefore *always* in red/yellow.

I know that this isn't a breaking issue -- the domains pointed to the beanstalk environment work just fine. I just can't seem to figure out if it is possible for the health check to include a domain name.

Comment: based on the lack of answers, I'm going to assume the answer is "no"